# How do I designate the infimum of the union of an indexed family of sets of real numbers using set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have an arbitrary collection of sets $\{U_i\}$ from the topology $\Omega := {\varnothing, [0, \infty)} \cup \{(a, \infty): a \in \mathbb{R}_{0+}\}$. In the case the arbitrary collection $\{U_i\}$ doesn't have either $\varnothing$ or $[0, \infty)$, the union of all its members $\bigcup U_i$ is $(a^*, \infty)$ where $a^*$ is the least such $a^*$. Now, for the life of me, I have been suffering trying to designate that set and its infimum with set theory. Is its infimum $a^* = \inf \{a_i : (a_i, \infty) \in U_i\}$? I want to say it is identical to $\inf \{x : (x, \infty) \in U_i \}$, but I'm not sure, I'm a bit confused by the notation. The problem (I think?) is that there's no hint that this set should range over all the possible $U_i$ sets (that have been defined $(a, \infty)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}_{0+}$) which are in the collection $\{U_i\}$ and grab only the value of the lower bound of the interval.

I feel like this designation should mention the indexing set somehow. Maybe  $\inf \{x : (x, \infty) \in U_i,  i \in I \}$? But in that case, don't I have to define the index set? And how would I define the index set of a collection that is arbitrary? Any hints, help, reading suggestions or keywords are highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the index set in your last example just be given from the collection of the $U_i$? Also your $U_i$s are subsets of $\mathbb R$ so you should write $(a, b) \subseteq U_i$ rather than $\in$. Since they are subsets of $\mathbb R$ you could just write $a^* = \inf \bigcup U_i$.

Comment: @user2271513 ah! thank you so much! those clarifications are exactly what I needed. feel free to add it as an answer to the question. small extra question, however: you mentioned the index set in my last example would be given from the collection of the $U_i$s, and that makes sense, but how would I define that index set, say, when I introduce the collection for the first time, if it is an arbitrary collection? it seems almost contradictory to say it would be an arbitrary index set, but nevertheless, it would be structured enough to be able to be used as a reference for indices

Comment: You can view a collection of sets $U_i$ as a map $f: I \to \Omega$, where $I$ is some set, and so an arbitrary collection will be an arbitrary $f$ from an arbitrary set $I$. It doesn't really make sense to talk about a collection without defining the indexing set.

Comment: very sincerely, thank you! I've been having a terrible time with this question for the past few hours, and this finally settles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like $$\inf \{x : (x, \infty) \in U_i \}$$ or $$\inf \{a_i : (a_i, \infty) \in U_i\}$$ is incorrect because $U_i$ refers to an interval (which depends on the index $i$), not a set of intervals, so it would not have something like $(x,\infty)$ or $(a_i,\infty)$ as an *element*.  A correct notation would be $$\inf \{x : (x, \infty) \in \{U_i\} \}$$ where you are instead writing $\{U_i\}$ for the *set* of all your intervals.  Another way to write it would be to first define $a_i$ to be the lower endpoint of $U_i$ for each $i$ in your index set $I$ (so $U_i=(a_i,\infty)$, and then take $$\inf\{a_i:i\in I\}.$$ (Note that it's better to first define $U_i=(a_i,\infty)$ *outside* of the set in the infimum, to avoid any confusion about the status of the variable $i$.  For instance, if you write $\inf \{a_i : (a_i, \infty) \in \{U_i\}\}$, in the expression $(a_i, \infty) \in \{U_i\}$ the two occurrences of $i$ actually have totally different meanings: in $\{U_i\}$ it is locally bound by the index set $I$ since $\{U_i\}$ really means $\{U_i:i\in I\}$, but in $(a_i,\infty)$ the entire expression $a_i$ is instead bound as the variable in the outer set definition.)

You ask about how to define the index set, but the index set is *already* given to you.  If you write $\{U_i\}$, that is an *abbreviation* for $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ (or $\{U_i:i\in I\}$) for some (perhaps unspecified) index set $I$.  So if you start with a family $\{U_i\}$, that by definition means that you *already have* an index set which you can freely refer to.  Alternatively, though, you don't need to use index notation at all.  You could instead just say you have a set $\mathcal{F}$ which is a subset of $\Omega$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is equal to the set you've been calling $\{U_i\}$ but with no need for any indexing.  You can then write your infimum as $$\inf \{x : (x, \infty) \in \mathcal{F} \}.$$  This is generally what I would recommend: unless there's some particular reason you want an indexing, you should just use a set, not an indexed family.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!